# How do you create new words if latin suffixes and prefixes are not sufficient in allowing you to create a new word you want to create?

Tags: technical-writing, science

How do you create new words if latin suffixes and prefixes are not sufficient in allowing you to create a new word you want to create? What are the things people use to make up for a lack of latin suffixes and prefixes to create any word imaginable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So forgive me, it's been a while, but Latin suffixes are sufficient for the language as their functions are to assist with sentence structure.  A sentance in Latin lacks word ordering in their sentences, though there is usually a prescribed order.  Compare this to English where the Verb always divides the sentence along the subject and predicate clauses.  In Latin, the placement of the words with respect to verb is not required, and the verb normally appears at the end of the sentance.  Consider the sentance in "Billy took his ball home" with a literaly translated version from Latin to English which would come as "Billy his ball home took".  The suffixes of each word in a sentence help denote the context in a statement.

In the case of verbs, the suffix change to the root word denotes both tense (past, present, future) and voice (active or passive).  With nouns, the suffixes denote speaker (first, second, or third person), gender (he, she, it), number (singular, plural) and whether the words is the subject or predicate of the verb.

For adjectives and adverbs, their suffix will be the same as the words they modify.

Prefixes, like in English, modify the specific root word and most of the english language prefixes have Latin roots.  Prefixes are used to change the meaning of word with respect to the original meaning of the root.